# Perl lvalue

Tags: perl

Допустим есть код :

```
my $value;
sub value : lvalue {
        $value;
}
value = 20;
print $value;
```

Что делает lvalue понятно , но есть ли возможность отследить, что бы присваиваемое значение было цифрой ? То есть поймать "20" перед присваением ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A normal mutator can check the
> supplied argument before setting the
> attribute it is protecting, an lvalue
> subroutine never gets that chance

Иными словами, в "нормальной" функции можно проверить аргументы:

```
my $value;
sub setval
{
    my ( $val ) = @_;
    croak 'Not a number' unless $val =~ /^\d+$/;
    $value = $val;
    $val;

}
```

В lvalue - нет. Да и вообще, "Lvalue subroutines are still experimental and the implementation may change in future versions of Perl." :-)

Answer (score 3):

Судя по описанию, модуль [`lvalue`](http://metacpan.org/module/lvalue) изменяет стандартное поведение и позволяет работать с переданным аргументом.

Comment: И правда :)

    use lvalue;

    my $value;
    sub v1 : lvalue 
    {
 set
 {
     my $val = shift;
     croak 'Not a number' unless $val =~ /^\d+$/;
     $value = $val;
     $value;
 }
    }